# Loop data into json?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I wanna loop  every appointment and put it in json like this :

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "title":"Test 1",
      "start":"2016-09-16 12:00:00",
      "end":"2016-09-16 14:00:00",
      "allDay":false
   },

   {
       "id":"2",
       "title":"Test 2",
       "start":"2016-09-15 12:00:00",
       "end":"2016-09-15 14:00:00",
       "allDay":false
   }
]
```

I have a table `appointments` in the database.

```
id | title  | appointment_date_start | appointment_date_end |
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Test 1 | 2016-09-16 12:00:00    | 2016-09-16 14:00:00  |
2  | Test 2 | 2016-09-15 12:00:00    | 2016-09-15 14:00:00  |
```

In my `feed.blade.php` I get all the data.
So i can do:

```
@foreach ($appointments as $appointments)

    {{ $appointment->id }}
    {{ $appointment->title }}
    {{ $appointment->appointment_date_start }}
    {{ $appointment->appointment_date_end }}

@endforeach
```

This outputs the data from the database. But how do I foreach it in a array?

Like

```
$event_array[] = array(
    'id' => {{ $appointment->id }},
    'title' => {{ $appointment->gender }},
    'start' => {{ $appointment->appointment_date_start }},
    'end' => {{ $appointment->appointment_date_end }},
    'allDay' => false
);
```

**Edit**

I tried this in my public function

```
public function feed()
{   
    $feed = Appointment::all();
    return $feed->toJson();
    return view('appointments/feed');
}
```

This is what I get

```
{
    id: 35,
    user_id: 1,
    gender: "men",
    appointment_date_start: "2016-09-14 20:00:00",
    appointment_date_end: "2016-09-14 20:40:00",
    created_at: "2016-09-16 08:16:16",
    updated_at: "2016-09-16 08:16:16"
}
```

I need to remove `gender, created_at and updated_at` and appointment_date_start should be start and appointment_date_end should be end? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove created_at and updated_at, just don't select the attributes while fetching the data from the database:

```
$feed = Appointment::select('id', 'user_id', 'appointment_date_start as start', 'appointment_date_end as end')->get(); 
// leave created_at and updated_at
// select('old as new') to change the attribute name
```

Then encode the array into json with `json_encode`

```
return json_encode($feed);
```

Comment: Yes it works but is there a way to change the name from appoinment_date_start to start?

Answer (score 1):

You can just go `{{ $appointments->toJson() }}`, is that what you want?

Comment: I think your question is answered, is it?